# Could not build module 'Darwin' on xcode 7.1

Tags: ios9.1, xcode7.1

I'm facing wired problem after installing Xcode 7.1. While I'm running existing project (Previously successfully built on Xcode 7) I'm getting error like this:

```
1.  Could not build module 'Darwin' on #import <Availability.h>

2. Cannot open file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk/usr/include/mach/message.h': Invalid argument on #include <mach/arm/thread_state.h>
```

Just look at the screenshot you will find more.

[image]

I also removed the frameworks and imported the latest one avilable on Xcode 7.1 and iOS 9.1. But still I have the same issue.
Please help.

Comment: You've blotted out the interesting stuff.  That error that "While building module 'UIKit' imported from /User/-------" is interesting as `UIKit.h` is not normally found under `/User`.  So your system is unusual for starters.  Please elaborate.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Previously I had Xcode 7. This project is working perfectly  on Xcode 7.Then I uninstalled it and installed  Xcode 7.1 and after opening this existing project I found those errors. And the interesting part is if I create a new project then, it runs flawlessly. So, did you understand the problem?

Comment: I want to know why `UIKit.h` is being read from `/Users` rather than `/Applications/Xcode.app`.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Don't know. But I double checked in my applications the the Xcode 7.1 is not under `Users`

Comment: @trojanfoe: And it solved without changing anything. I copied the project from orginal backup and after opeing it Xcode 7.1, the errors are gone. Looks like it was indexing problem of Xcode 7.1. Xcode 7 and Xcode 7.1 are the most buggy app than other xcode versions.

Comment: @trojanfoe: thanks for your cooperation.